# Combine scraped data from several webpages into single page

Tags: java, php, javascript, aggregate, web-scraping

I want to create a webpage which aggregates data from several webpages, in a similar manner to what the IE Web Slice, WebChunks, PageSlices or [other web slices does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Slice).

It can be either a website (or just html page, locally) or desktop application which works as kind of an aggregator.

What is the way of doing so? Java, Javascript, PHP,  desktop application or other?
In addition, can you provide with some reference of scraping single div with known ID < div id="ThisIsIt">  from several different webpages and presenting them in one piece (as web page, or application)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php with DOMDocument class it will be

```
$url='....bla bla';
$out=file_get_contents($url);
$dom=new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($out);

$div=$dom->getElementById('yourid');
$value=$div->nodeValue;
```